# ember.js and handlebars registerHelper function

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Im strating to implement ember in my project and i cant find a way to support basic handlebars functions.

What I need is a list with a < br> tag after first 4 < li> items.
The Handlebars site suggets such function

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('list', function(context, options) {
  var ret = "<ul>";
  for(var i=0, j=context.length; i<j; i++) {
    ret = ret + "<li>" + options.fn(context[i]) + "</li>";
    if(i==3){
        ret += '<br id="ok">' 
    }
  }
 return ret + "</ul>";
});
```

The object:

```
 var Test = [
    { url: "http://www.yehudakatz.com", title: "Katz Got Your Tongue" },
    { url: "http://www.sproutcore.com/block2", title: "SproutCore Blog" },
    { url: "http://www.sproutcore.com/block", title: "ssss Blog" },
    { url: "http://www.Blog.com/block", title: "BlogBlog" },
  ];
```

Ember code:

```
App.TestRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return Test;
  }
});
```

Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="Test">
    <div>
        <span>test</span>
    </div>
    {{#each model}}
         <a href="{{url}}">{{title}}</a>
    {{/each}} 
  </script>
```

But as a result, the object is either parsed as string, giving 5 (5 letters in 'model' word) empty iterations (with < br> though).

However, if I use #each, the object is parsed, But my links look like this:

```
 < a href="&lt;script id='metamorph-7-start' type='text/x-placeholder'&gt;&lt;/script&gt;http://www.yehudakatz.com&lt;script id='metamorph-7-end' type='text/x-placeholder'&gt;&lt;/script&gt;"><script id="metamorph-8-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>Katz Got Your Tongue<script id="metamorph-8-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>< /a>
```

Please give me a hint how to solve the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ember change some things in handlebars helpers to enable binding, so this is why your html have that metamorph tags. To use plain handlebars helpers without ember stuff you can change your template type to `text/x-raw-handlebars`:

```
<script type="text/x-raw-handlebars" id="Test">
    <div>
        <span>test</span>
    </div>    
    {{#list content}}
        <a href="{{url}}">{{title}}</a>
    {{/list}}
</script>
```

And use `Handlebars.registerHelper` instead of `Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper`:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('list', function(context, options) {
  var ret = "<ul>";    
  for(var i=0, j=context.length; i<j; i++) {
    ret = ret + "<li>" + options.fn(context[i]) + "</li>";
    if(i==3){
        ret += '<br id="ok">' 
    }
  }
 return ret + "</ul>";
});
```

You can see this in action in that fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/vzsUN/

If your url doesn't need to update by bindings you can use the `unbound` view helper:

```
 <a {{unbound url}}>{{title}}</a>
```

Otherwise you can use the `bindAttr` view helper:

```
 <a {{bindAttr href="url"}}>{{title}}</a>
```

This wil create a data attribute instead of a metamorph tag, and your html will not break.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a {{bind-attr href="url"}}>{{title}}</a>
```

Comment: this is {{bind-attr... now I think  : )